# Could not load assembly, Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040

Tags: wpf, charts, wpf-controls, visifire

**Exception:**

**Could not load file or assembly 'WPFVisifire.Charts, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=99d724542e4db593' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

We are working with our stock exchange charting application using Visifire. We have two app versions. Online Silverlight version and desktop WPF version. I already created Silverlight application and its working well. Same code I copied in WPF application but WPF chart application throws exception.

I’m very new to dot net development. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using Windows7 OS?

I suggest you to follow the steps below.

1. Remove reference of WPFVisifire.Charts.dll and WPFToolkit.dll (if
   used) from your project.
2. Clean your project.
3. Close the application.
4. Right click no WPFVisifire.Charts.dll and WPFToolkit.dll(if used) then click on properties.
5. Go to General Tab.
6. Click on Unblock button.
7. Now open your project in Visual Studio.
8. Add new reference to unblocked WPFVisifire.Charts.dll and
   WPFToolkit.dll(if used).
9. Compile your project and run.

Comment: On Windows 10 and 11 it's checkbox at the bottom of the file properties dialog's general tab.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71645944/3969362