# How to identify cause of Assembly issue?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I'm getting an error in a new unfamiliar area to me, SharePoint development. I'm trying to debug my solution via Visual Studio 2012 and I get the following error as recorded in the EventLog:

Exception information:

> ```
> Exception type: FileLoadException 
> Exception message: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the 
>   assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
> ```

The error is seen within the .ascx.g.cs for my control, in a @__BuildControlTree method. Unfortunately it doesn't tell me the name of the assembly, so I'm not sure where the error lies. The stack trace reported is:

> Stack trace:
>   at MI.VWP.Chart.Chart.CreateChildControls()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.Part.get_Controls()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.AddParsedSubObject(Object obj)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.AddParsedSubObject(Object
>   obj)    at
>   MooDInternational.VisualWebParts.Chart.Chart.__BuildControlTree(Chart
>   __ctrl)    at MooDInternational.VisualWebParts.Chart.Chart.InitializeControl()    at
>   MooDInternational.VisualWebParts.Chart.Chart.OnInit(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartManager.WebPartManagerControlCollection.AddWebPartHelper(WebPart
>   webPart)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartManager.WebPartManagerControlCollection.AddWebPart(WebPart
>   webPart)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartManagerInternals.AddWebPart(WebPart
>   webPart)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.AddWebPartWithRetry(WebPart
>   webPart)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.CreateWebPartsFromRowSetData(Boolean
>   onlyInitializeClosedWebParts)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.LoadWebParts()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.OnPageInitComplete(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)    at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInitComplete(EventArgs e)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

I don't however get a call to that method if I attempt to set a breakpoint there. I've tried looking at fusionlog but get the following which I don't think helps...

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (13/09/2012 @ 14:16:15) ***

> The operation was successful. Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation
>   completed successfully.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll Running
>   under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SharePoint\vssphost4.exe
>   --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: User = ******.***** LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a  (Fully-specified)
>   LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0/Common7/IDE/Extensions/Microsoft/SharePoint/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SharePoint\VstspCache10724 LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL LOG: Cache Base = NULL LOG: AppName = NULL Calling
>   assembly : (Unknown). LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>   LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SharePoint\vssphost4.exe.Config LOG: Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from
>   C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Framework\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll.
>   LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.

Can anyone make any suggestions on how I might resolve this issue?

**EDIT**

Using Reflector I managed to debug into the generated @_BuildControl method a little, and discover a call to AddParsedSubject(object child) which is a virtual method on a control.

Adding the following code:

```
protected override void AddParsedSubObject(object obj)
{
  System.Web.UI.Control child = obj as System.Web.UI.Control;
  if (child != null)
  {
    try
    {
       base.AddParsedSubObject(obj);
       System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Added " + child.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Error with " + child.ToString() + " : " + ex.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

This told me that the control causing the issue was a DevExpress.XtraCharts.Web.WebChartControl, so know I've tracked the assembly down to one of the DevExpress ones, not 100% sure which and not yet sure how to fix it.

Comment: Just realised I should add - I can Clean/Deploy/Debug my solution and it works, but this is awkward to do over and over. I'd like a simple F5 to just work.

Comment: See this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202065/could-not-load-assembly-exception-from-hresult-0x80131040

Comment: @Oscar: I'm not sure that the resolution steps would help, but still... my issue is I don't even know which assembly is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In asp.net this kind of errors means that old references are not been replaced in bin or temp asp.net folder. I would clean those folders an rebuild my project if i was you..

Comment: I seem to have to clean / redeploy every single time I make a code change though.

Comment: Actually, even this doesn't seem reliable. I tried a Clean then F5 with exactly the same error.

Comment: In the end I found repairing my install of the suite of controls and re-deploying fixed my issue.