# System.IO.FileLoadException - Could not load file or Assembly Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I have a web service that downloads a file from a Windows Azure Service Bus. However as soon as I call the method that connects to azure to download the file I get the following error.

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in MyWebService.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=3.1.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have checked the versions of azure I am using and all are version 3.1.0.1.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the Problem in your case is Windows is blocking the DLL from being referenced .
You need to first "**Unblock**" it first and then add Refernce ..

Refer this link : [Could not load assembly, Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202065/could-not-load-assembly-exception-from-hresult-0x80131040)

Comment: On Windows 10 and 11 it's checkbox at the bottom of the file properties dialog's general tab.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the DLL in file explorer to open the properties dialog.
On Windows 10 and 11 at the bottom of the general tab there is a checkbox you need to tick to enable use of your DLL.

[image]