# Why i'm getting System.IO.FileLoadException?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In form1 designer I have menustrip with Open menu.

Just dragged from toolbox menustrip added Open menu.

when running the program and clicking the Open I can't use a break point it's not even get there but throw this exception first:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.dll' or one of its dependencies.
>   is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)

The exception is in `Program.cs` on the line

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

Not sure what is going on here. Maybe something messed up with the designer ?
My project is set to .net 4.5 and to Any CPU I tried to set it to .net 4 and to x86 but same exception.

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915120/system-io-fileloadexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-windowsa

Comment: [Check out Hans Passant's answer here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26329259/106159) You might want to start using [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) instead.

Comment: Ok I managed to fix it I guess by adding another version of the Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.dll to my project and also set the app.config file I added to the file the line: useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" also set the target to x86(but not sure not tested if x86 is a must)